# mysql: difference between primary key and unique index?

Tags: sql, mysql

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the difference between a primary key and a unique constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308593/what-is-the-difference-between-a-primary-key-and-a-unique-constraint)
>   [Primary key or Unique index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487314/primary-key-or-unique-index)

i need to change one of the fields of a table to auto increment and to be the primary key. what does unique index mean?