# Which column we should choose as primary key if we have 2 unique columns

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key, unique-key, rdbms

I know what's the difference between unique and primary key as explained in following links

http://sqlhints.com/2013/06/02/difference-between-primary-key-and-unique-key-in-sql-server/
[difference between primary key and unique key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565996/difference-between-primary-key-and-unique-key)

but I was asked something different in an interview ,

> If I have 2 columns in a table which can uniquely identify
>   entries , say student's roll no and national id no. Then which one
>   I'll select as primary key and what's the difference between primary
>   and unique key if we add not null constraint on unique key.

Any help regarding this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this too [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404730/what-is-difference-between-unique-key-with-not-null-constraint-and-primary-key]

Answer (score 1):

I am a big advocate of the third way -- having an auto-incremented, integer primary key.  You can then put unique indexes on the others.

Such a key offers several things.  First, it allows you to determine the order of insertion of records -- at least to a close approximation.  Second, it makes foreign key references easier.  I typically name such columns `<tablename>Id`, which makes external references obvious.

Third, integers are a pretty efficient mechanism for indexes (fixed width values, typically four bytes).  Admittedly, they do incur a bit of overhead in the original table, but that is usually minor.

Fourth, the columns may not be applicable.  In the United States, the closest we have to a national id number is a social security number -- and it is not guaranteed to be unique.  Further, there may be students who enroll in the school that do not have such numbers -- foreign students, for instance.