# How can I create a unique index in Oracle but ignore nulls?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I am trying to create a unique constraint on two fields in a table.  However, there is a high likelihood that one will be null.  I only require that they be unique if both are not null (`name` will never be null).

```
create unique index "name_and_email" on user(name, email);
```

Ignore the semantics of the table and field names and whether that makes sense - I just made some up.

Is there a way to create a unique constraint on these fields that will enforce uniqueness for two not null values, but ignore if there are multiple entries where `name` is not null and `email` is null?

This question is for SQL Server, and I'm hoping that the answer is not the same:
[How do I create a unique constraint that also allows nulls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767657/how-do-i-create-unique-constraint-that-also-allows-nulls-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

We can do this with a function-based index.  The following makes use of `NVL2()` which, as you know, returns one value if the expression is not null and a different value if it is null.  You could use `CASE()` instead.

```
SQL> create table blah (name varchar2(10), email varchar2(20))
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> create unique index blah_uidx on blah
  2      (nvl2(email, name, null), nvl2(name, email, null))
  3  /

Index created.

SQL> insert into blah values ('APC', null)
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> insert into blah values ('APC', null)
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> insert into blah values (null, 'apc@example.com')
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> insert into blah values (null, 'apc@example.com')
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> insert into blah values ('APC', 'apc@example.com')
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> insert into blah values ('APC', 'apc@example.com')
  2  /
insert into blah values ('APC', 'apc@example.com')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (APC.BLAH_UIDX) violated


SQL>
```

**Edit**

Because in your scenario name will always be populated you will only need an index like this:

```
SQL> create unique index blah_uidx on blah
  2      (nvl2(email, name, null), email)
  3  /

Index created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how many people still get directed to this answer, but at least in the latest version of oracle, you're allowed to have multiple rows with null on a unique index and the accepted answer isn't necessary

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the doco about this please?  I can't find this and my experience is that I am unable to do this - may be wrong version.