# Oracle: Create unique index but ignore NULLs

Tags: oracle11g

I came across this example on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374737/how-can-i-create-a-unique-index-in-oracle-but-ignore-nulls) which gives a solution to create a unique index by ignoring nulls. However, I want to extend it and I am not able reach to a solution.

I have a composite index for 3 columns of a table (there are other 10 columns in the table). These columns are not part of PK. Of these 3 columns, 2 will always hold some value and 3rd may be NULL. I have huge test data, and there are many inserts with 2 of the columns with same value and 3rd column NULL.  These all inserts work well for PostgreSQL, however Oracle complains. For my test cases to work, I think the simplest solution that I think is to try a unique index for Oracle that would work as it works in PostgreSQL.

Precisely: I want a construct of following kind, not sure how to combine `col1 + col2 + col3`

```
create unique index tbl_idx on tbl (nvl2(col3, col1 + col2, col1 + col2 + col3))
```

I am using liquibase. Index is created in following way -

```
<changeSet dbms="postgresql,oracle" author="abc" id="222">
    <createIndex indexName="Index_7" schemaName="ss" tableName="Users" unique="true">
        <column name="idOrganization"/>
        <column name="strUsername"/>
        <column name="strNotDeleted"/>
    </createIndex>
</changeSet>
```

I am using liquibase to create my test data, here are two insert statements

```
<insert schemaName="ss" tableName="Users">
    <column name="strUsername" value="user1" />
    <column name="idUser" valueNumeric="20741" />
    <column name="idOrganization" valueNumeric="4" />
    <column name="strFirstName" value="user" />
    <column name="strLastName" value="one" />
    <column name="strEmail" value="email@foo.com" />
    <column name="strNotDeleted" />
</insert>
<insert schemaName="ss" tableName="Users">
    <column name="strUsername" value="user1" />
    <column name="idUser" valueNumeric="20771" />
    <column name="idOrganization" valueNumeric="4" />
    <column name="strFirstName" value="user" />
    <column name="strLastName" value="one" />
    <column name="strEmail" value="email@foo.com" />
    <column name="strNotDeleted" />
</insert>
```

These 2 inserts work fine for PostgreSQL, however fail for Oracle with error "Index_7 constraint violation".

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem you are trying to solve.  If you created the simplest possible unique constraint, `alter table table_name add constraint uk_table_name unique( col1, col2, col3 )`, what row(s) are excluded that you want to allow and/or what row(s) are included that you want to disallow?

Comment: @JustinCave: Updated my question, I hope it gives a better picture.

Comment: What does "Oracle complains" mean, exactly?  Is there an error message?  If so, what error?  A simple composite unique index on `col1, col2, col3` would allow you to insert an unlimited number of rows where `col1` and `col2` are identical and  `col3 IS NULL`.  It sounds like you are saying that is what you want and that is not what you observe so it would help to post a small test case that shows what you are trying to achieve and what error you get.

Comment: @JustinCave: Another edit to the question done.

Comment: This MUST raise a constraint violation. You are creating a unique index and the values that form the index are absolutely the same; any other behavior would be a bug. It sounds like you don't want a unique index.

Comment: Postgres documentation says: `When an index is declared unique, multiple table rows with equal indexed values are not allowed. Null values are not considered equal. A multicolumn unique index will only reject cases where all indexed columns are equal in multiple rows.` - Does that mean that the records will give **DIFFERENT INDEXES** if 1 column is NULL and other 2 columns have same value in 2 record instance?

Comment: OK.  So what is an example of an insert that you would want to fail?  Do you only want to prevent duplicates when `strNotDeleted` is set to a non-NULL value?

Comment: Ahh, for Postgres it works because they consider `NULL != NULL`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the goal is only to prevent duplicates where `strNotDeleted` is set to a non-NULL value, then you want a function-based index like this

```
SQL> create table users(
  2    idOrganization number,
  3    strUsername    varchar2(100),
  4    strNotDeleted  varchar2(3)
  5  );

Table created.


SQL> create unique index idx_users
  2      on users( (case when strNotDeleted is not null
  3                      then idOrganization
  4                      else null
  5                  end),
  6                (case when strNotDeleted is not null
  7                      then strUsername
  8                      else null
  9                 end) );

Index created.
```

This allows the two rows you mention in your question to be inserted

```
SQL> insert into users values( 4, 'user', null );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into users values( 4, 'user', null );

1 row created.
```

You can insert one row where the `strNotNull` column is set to a non-NULL value

```
SQL> insert into users values( 4, 'user', 'Yes' );

1 row created.
```

But you then can't insert a second such row

```
SQL> insert into users values( 4, 'user', 'Yes' );
insert into users values( 4, 'user', 'Yes' )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.IDX_USERS) violated
```

Behind the scenes, an Oracle b*-tree index does not index completely `NULL` entries.  The two `CASE` statements ensure that the index only has entries for `idOrganization` and `strUsername` if `strNotDeleted` is not `NULL`.  If `strNotDeleted` is `NULL`, then both `CASE` statements evaluate to `NULL` and no entry is made in the index.  Conceptually, it's similar to a partial index in other databases which allows you to specify a `WHERE` clause on your index so that you only index "interesting" rows.

Comment: Simple question so that I understand. Is your method of creating index equivalent to `create unique index idx_users on users (idOrganization, strUsername, strNotDeleted)`?

Comment: @gotuskar - No, this is different.  A straight composite index on those three columns would disallow the second and fourth inserts.

Comment: In the create index statement, why both cases have same check, i.e. `strNotDeleted is not null`. If your could please explain in detail.

Comment: I tried writing following query `create unique index NDX_ExternalId_OrgId on "ss"."Users" ((case when ("strExternalId" is not null and "strNotDeleted" is not null) then "idOrganization" else null end) );` but it did not work, I still got violation error.

Comment: @gotuskar - Where did `strExternalId` come from?  What was the `INSERT` that caused the constraint violation?  Is the goal, as I asked in the first part of my answer, "to prevent duplicates where strNotDeleted is set to a non-NULL value"?  I'm still not sure that I understand exactly what you are trying to allow and what you are trying to disallow.  The code I posted handles the one case you've posted thus far but I'm not sure that I fully understand what you're trying to accomplish yet.

Comment: The one that you provided worked fine. I will accept that answer. I had one more scenario, wherein I wanted to index only if all three fields are available. Of the three fields, two fields may be null. I was trying out a new query based on your previous one, but that did not work.

Comment: @gotuskar - Can you give an example of inserts that you would want to succeed and inserts that you would want to fail?

Comment: If all 3 columns have values, then its `INDEX` should be unique. `idOrganization` will always have value. `strExternalId` and `strNotDeleted` may be null. So multiple `INSERTS` should work even if same `idOrganization` has same value. For columns `(idOrganization, strExternalId, strNotDeleted)`: `insert into users values( 4, 'user', null );`, `insert into users values( 4, null, null );`, `insert into users values( 4, null, '1' );`, `insert into users values( 4, 'user', '1' );` all should work. But `insert into users values( 4, 'user', '1' );` should not, since an entry exists.

Comment: @gotuskar - A straight composite index on `idOrganization`, `strExternalId`, and `strNotDeleted` would allow the first 4 `INSERT` operations and reject the last one.  Is there an `INSERT` that you want to allow that a straight composite index would reject or an `INSERT` that you want to disallow that a straight composite index would allow?

Comment: I can have multiple inserts of the first four kind. I want all of them to pass. Multiple inserts of `insert into users values( 4, 'user', null );` should pass.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> create table users(
      idOrganization number,
      strUsername    varchar2(100),
      strNotDeleted  varchar2(3)
   )
SQL> /

Table created.

SQL> Create unique index idx_users
    on users(
         (
           case when strNotDeleted is not null
                      then idOrganization
                        else null
             end
          ),
          (
           case when strNotDeleted is not null
                       then strUsername
                       else null
           end
         ),
         (
           case when strNotDeleted is not null
                      then strNotDeleted
                       else null
           end
         )
   )
SQL> /

Index created.
```