# android sqlite index on null column

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table and would like to create 3 columns unique index. The problem is that one of column can have null values. As you probably know sqlite treats those values in special way and if we have

```
row1: A, B, null
row2: A, B, null
```

It will be accepted (even if I created unique index on A, B, C).

The question is if there is any trick which could treat null as the same value as all others (ex. null is zero) and in the case above, second row wouldn't be accepted as violating the rules.

THanks in advance for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create unique index on fields with possible null values (Oracle 11g)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042997/how-to-create-unique-index-on-fields-with-possible-null-values-oracle-11g)

Comment: @njzk2 SQLite does not have function indexes.

Answer (score 1):

you could try to create the table with column-3 having a default value (of zero, for example), not allowing NULL, so that when it's NOT included in the INSERT, it would just take the default value.  This would keep unique index.

Comment: No way. But I'm wondering if it's possible to create some kind of logical column in sqlite3. I mean the column not stored in database, but being calculated as: new column = (0 if C is null, otherwise C). How to do that and is that possible to set index on logical column?

Comment: @user2707175 Do you mean [ROWID](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)? Or [VIEW](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Too late but had to find the solution for myself.

[Unique Partial Indexes](https://www.sqlite.org/partialindex.html#unique_partial_indexes)

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_index ON my_table(field_a, field_b, field_c) WHERE field_c IS NOT NULL;