# Null value isn't unique

Tags: database, postgresql, null

I have rows like these on postgres:

```
 name | address | college 

 john | rome    |
 john | rome    |
 max  | tokyo   |
```

I create a table like this:

```
create test (
name    varchar(10),
address varchar(20),
college varchar(20),
constraint test_uq unique (name,address,college);
```

How can I make null values become unique, so the output can be like this:

```
 name | address | college 

 john | rome    |
 max  | tokyo   |
```

Comment: Related question about MySQL and non-unique nulls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081783/unique-key-with-nulls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres documentation [claims](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/ddl-constraints.html) that this behaviour is compliant with the SQL standard:

> In general, a unique constraint is violated when there are two or more
>   rows in the table where the values of all of the columns included in
>   the constraint are equal. However, two null values are not considered
>   equal in this comparison. That means even in the presence of a unique
>   constraint it is possible to store duplicate rows that contain a null
>   value in at least one of the constrained columns. This behavior
>   conforms to the SQL standard[.]

One possibility is to rethink your schema (to be honest, a uniqueness constraint on `name+address+college` doesn't make a whole lots of sense in your example).

Comment: oh my..so null value isnt be unique? so how to avoid redudancy data ?
in my real table, i insert the record into table which in that table the unique constraint is true, then i insert again the same record, and that same record inserted to table, finally in that table there's 2 same record :(

Answer (score 2):

If you just need unique records in the query result use `SELECT DISTINCT`

```
 
postgres=# SELECT * FROM test;
 name | address | college 
------+---------+---------
 john | rome    | 
 john | rome    | 
 max  | tokyo   | 
(3 rows)

postgres=# SELECT DISTINCT * FROM test;
 name | address | college 
------+---------+---------
 john | rome    | 
 max  | tokyo   | 
(2 rows)
```

If you want to enforce unique records ignoring null values you must create a [conditional unique index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html)

```
postgres=# CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_index ON test (name, address) WHERE college IS NULL;
CREATE INDEX
postgres=# INSERT INTO test (name, address) VALUES ('john', 'rome');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# INSERT INTO test (name, address) VALUES ('max', 'tokyo');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# INSERT INTO test (name, address, college) VALUES ('john', 'rome', 'college');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# INSERT INTO test (name, address) VALUES ('john', 'rome');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_index"
DETAIL:  Key (name, address)=(john, rome) already exists.
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you make it a primary key, instead of a unique constraint, it would work. For that, the column `college` would have to be `NOT NULL` and use (for instance) empty strings instead of NULL values.
Or are you looking for a query?

Comment: i cant make it primary key, because in my real data, a few record has a value,

Comment: That is ok - even if some records have a value. You want that 2 records should not have the same (name,address,college) values, right?

Comment: So then if you make it a primary key it would not allow duplicate entries where all 3 columns are the same. Why don't you try it with a sample table and see if it works for you?

Comment: A primary key in postgres is simply [a combination of a unique constraint and a not-null constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html). No need for a primary key here. Just set the column `NOT NULL DEFAULT ''`, and you are done here.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thank you :) I was thinking mysql, missed the postgres.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yapp thx for your help. it works when i insert a new value to that table with the same data.

Answer (score 0):

NULL is unknown so a value of NULL being equal to NULL can never be true.  To work around this law do this.

Create a new look-up table for your colleges. In that table have a record with the value None. Then put a Foreign Key to the new college look-up table.

This is pseudo code so you may have to mess with it to make it work, but here is the basic idea.

```
CREATE TABLE college(college_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,college_type);
INSERT INTO college(college_type)
SELECT 1,None;


create test (
name varchar(10),
address varchar(20),
college_id INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
constraint test_uq unique (name,address,college_id);
```

Comment: hmm i dont wanna make it become 2 table, because in my real data, i have to make it 1 table, because the purpose of my data is make a summary_report.
but thanks for your answer. i aprociate it . thank you very much

Comment: You can still do what I was saying but leave out the new table and instead replace NULL in your existing college table with NO COLLEGE or NA.

Comment: so i give the default value for college, then give the college constraint not null?

Comment: Right, I believe that should get you out of your current issue.