# Mysql unique field will not accept multiple nulls

Tags: mysql, sql, null, unique

I have a table containing a video_id field which is set to unique accept NULL values.  However it will not accept two null values.  Table type InnoDB or MYISAM will not work.

This produces a duplicate key error on video _id (Null value):

```
INSERT INTO dances (name, video_id, level) VALUES ('abc', '', 'beg');
```

If I read the Mysql rules correctly it should do so. Can anyone suggest where to go next?

Comment: show your create table statement

Comment: Show a small example (`CREATE TABLE`, `INSERT` a few rows) where this occurs. You can use **[sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/)**

Comment: Have you by chance added a `DEFAULT x` attribute to the column?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, MySQL allows multiple NULLs in a column with a unique constraint. See [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712222/does-mysql-ignore-null-values-on-unique-constraints).

An empty string `''` is not the same as `NULL`.

Use this instead:

```
INSERT INTO dances (name, video_id, level) VALUES ('abc', NULL, 'beg');
```

Comment: INSERT INTO `dances`( `name`, `video_id`, `level`) VALUES ('abc', '', 'beg')  this produces a duplicate key error on video _id (Null value)

Comment: @TerryWright An empty string `''` is not the same as `NULL`.

Comment: @TerryWright: Use this:  INSERT INTO dances( name, video_id, level) VALUES ('abc', null, 'beg')

Answer (score 1):

You could try BDB (about which I know nothing); see [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,53591,53591) for more.

Comment: Didn't know that changing the underlying engines enabled this...

Comment: This reference seems to support my understanding that in InnoDB multiple Nulls should work. Thanks for the ref anyway.

Answer (score 0):

And why do you need multiple rows of your table to have a null video_id?

From a DB design perspective, it sounds like the object you are modelling with the table is too "big" and needs to be broken up into a main table and detail tables.

Your options are (A) remove the UNIQUE constraint, or (B) create a separate table that contains `object_id`, `video_id` pairs (`where object_id` is whatever the **primary key** is on your `main table`).

Comment: The table is a very simple one :- id, dance name, Video-id, dance level.  The id refers to youtube video of the dance but some don't have one.  In practical terms I could do away with the unique constraint but I don't understand why the Nulls produce a Duplicate Key failure. According to the Mysql info it should be ok.  Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @TerryWright From a data modelling perspective, each row of a table of dances describes the properties of a dance.  When a dance has 0 or more of something else, that is not really a property of a dance but a "has a" relationship that often gets a separate table.  Perhaps in the system you are developing there is only 0 or 1 videos per dance, and it might be desirable to keep things simple,  but a data modeller might say, hey, a dance could have lots of videos, and a long video could also show several dances, possibly necessitating a table of (dance_id,video_id) pairs as described.