# MySql Unique Index On Null Column

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql table with columns A (DateTime) and B (Int32). I want to create an index on this table that prevents duplicate values in A and B such that the following statement would fail:
`sql
Insert Into Table(A, B) Values (null, 2);
Insert Into Table(A, B) Values (null, 2);#should fail do to duplicate values`

I have created a unique index on columns A and B but it doesn't work for null values. Is there any way to reject this case?

Comment: if null should be stopped from being a duplicate, then there's no point having a null value. Just use zero or some other value instead.

Comment: null is not a value, it's a `null`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712222/does-mysql-ignore-null-values-on-unique-constraints

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does MySQL ignore null values on unique constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712222/does-mysql-ignore-null-values-on-unique-constraints)