# MariaDB (Xampp) Unique Constraint

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have created a test table with constraint Unique (column username), using mariaDB (10.3 v) which installed by default with Xammp.
What i m doing wrong ? is this accept NULL ??

[image]
 Please help once [image: Snapshot]

```
select * from tbltest \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       id: 1
full_name: user1
**user_name: NULL**
   status: 1
      age: 19
*************************** 2. row ***************************
       id: 2
full_name: user2
**user_name: NULL**
   status: 1
      age: 20
*************************** 3. row ***************************
       id: 3
full_name: user3
**user_name: NULL**
   status: 0
      age: 20
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: Even at 500%  magnification the image is unreadable can you add your table definition as text and expand on 'What i m doing wrong ? is this accept NULL ??'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does MySQL ignore null values on unique constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712222/does-mysql-ignore-null-values-on-unique-constraints)

Answer (score 0):

Line up the columns; it may be obvious what you did wrong:

```
INSERT ... ( full_name, status, age )
  VALUES   ( 'user2',   TRUE,   20  )
```