# Is it necessary to make a uqiue indexed column not nullable (SQL, SQLAlchemy)?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Not exactly sure where to post this question. Is it necessary to make an unique indexed column not nullable, like this (using SQLAlchemy):

```py
name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)  # <--
```

Or perhaps it's redundant and this column can't be NULL anyway? Can a unique column be NULL?

Comment: That depends on the database. For example, in MySQL, you would need to set `nullable=False` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712222/does-mysql-ignore-null-values-on-unique-constraints?rq=1. In the case of SQLA itself, I'm not sure whether it has standardised behaviour or just relies on the underlying libraries

Comment: In many DBMS having both `index=True` and `unique=True` is redundant, since unique constraints are enforced using a unique index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a unique column can be NULL. You will still need to use `nullable=False` if you want to control this.

If you omit `nullable=False` then the exact behaviour depends on the dialect. Some will allow multiple NULL values, others will only allow a single NULL when testing for uniqueness.

Firstly, we can see the following [from the source code](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py#L1148)

> :param nullable: When set to `False`, will cause the "NOT NULL"
>               phrase to be added when generating DDL for the column.   When
>               `True`, will normally generate nothing (in SQL this defaults to
>               "NULL"), except in some very specific backend-specific edge cases
>               where "NULL" may render explicitly.   Defaults to `True` unless
>               :paramref:`~.Column.primary_key` is also `True`, in which case it
>               defaults to `False`.  This parameter is only used when issuing
>               CREATE TABLE statements.

I can't cover all dialects but my searches seem to suggest that most will allow multiple NULL entries in a column with a unique constraint e.g. [the SQLite FAQ](https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q26) states:

> **The SQL standard requires that a UNIQUE constraint be enforced even if one or more of the columns in the constraint are NULL, but SQLite
>   does not do this. Isn't that a bug?**
>
> ...
>
> SQLite follows interpretation (1), as does PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle,
>   and Firebird. It is true that Informix and Microsoft SQL Server use
>   interpretation (2), however we the SQLite developers hold that
>   interpretation (1) is the most natural reading of the requirement and
>   we also want to maximize compatibility with other SQL database
>   engines, and most other database engines also go with (1), so that is
>   what SQLite does.