# Mobile number is unique, while Facebook login it give error

Tags: facebook, eloquent

Actually I am Login with Facebook and Facebook only gives me ID, Name, and Email. But in my database table, the Phone number field is unique.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a column nullable and unique, that means you can set it to null but when filled it will be unique, [Please see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712222/does-mysql-ignore-null-values-on-unique-constraints#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20MySQL%20allows%20multiple%20NULLs,column%20with%20a%20unique%20constraint.&text=This%20is%20not%20true%20for,that%20has%20a%20unique%20constraint.&text=This%20applies%20to%20all%20engines%20but%20BDB.)