How to prevent MySQL table from accepting multiple rows with NULL column value
How can I configure a MySQL table to prevent multiple rows having NULL in a given column when all other column values are equivalent?
I have a table with the following structure to store the favorite fruit of each user at each customer. I also need to store the favorite fruit of the customer institutionally without regard for a specific user:
CREATE TABLE TempTable ( 
    ID VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
    Customer VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
    Fruit VARCHAR(128), 
    User VARCHAR(64) 
); 

For example:
ID 1, Bank of Commerce, Apple, NULL
ID 2, Bank of Commerce, Banana, John
ID 3, Bank of Commerce, Pear, Danielle 

I need to make sure that duplicate entries don't get entered for the same customer/user OR for the same customer (without a user).
For example, given the above three rows, NEITHER of the following should be able to be inserted:
ID 4, Bank of Commerce, Orange, NULL
ID 5, Bank of Commerce, Mango, Danielle

The following unique constraint doesn't work because MySQL disregards NULL:
ALTER TABLE TempTable ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (`ID`, `Customer`, `Fruit`, `User`);

What is a suitable solution? Thank you very much for any help.

There's no User column in the table. Did you mean CustomerContact?

Could you use an empty string instead of NULL in the CustomerContact column?

Unfortunately, MySQL ignores null values when checking unique constraints. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712222/does-mysql-ignore-null-values-on-unique-constraints

You can add generated column and use it as part of your constraint instead of using CustomerContact:: ALTER TABLE TempTable ADD COLUMN uniquecust varchar(64) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (IFNULL(CustomerContact, '')) NOT NULL;
