# Check for duplicate column values (not a key) in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Is there a way for SQL to enforce unique column values, that are not a primary key to another table?

For instance, say I have `TblDog` which has the fields:

1. `DogId` - `Primary Key`
2. `DogTag` - `Integer`
3. `DogNumber` - `varchar`

The `DogTag` and `DogNumber` fields must be unique, but are not linked to any sort of table.

The only way I can think of involves pulling any records that match the `DogTag` and pulling any records that match the `DogNumber` before creating or editing (excluding the current record being updated.) This is two calls to the database before even creating/editing the record.

**My question is**: is there a way to set SQL to enforce these values to be unique, without setting them as a key, or in `Entity Frameworks` (without excessive calls to the DB)?

I understand that I could group the two calls in one, but I need to be able to inform the user exactly which field has been duplicated (or both).

Edit: The database is SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: could you use Guids? Or a unique constraint?

Comment: No, I can't used Guids. The types cannot be changed.

Comment: Are you looking for [Unique Constraints](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/02/05/sql-server-primary-key-constraints-and-unique-key-constraints/)?

Comment: Or a unique index, depending on the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest setting [unique constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)/[indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224827%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to prevent duplicate entries.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. From what I read, there can only be one `NULL` value in the entire table? These are fields that also can be `NULL`. Or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: IIRC, you're right. However from sql server 2008+ you're in luck... http://stackoverflow.com/a/767702/14357 ... you can set constraint to ignore null columns.

Answer (score 4):

As MilkywayJoe suggests, use unique key constraints in the SQL database. These are checked during inserts + Updates.

```
ALTER TABLE TblDog ADD CONSTRAINT U_DogTag UNIQUE(DogTag)
```

AND

```
ALTER TABLE TblDog ADD CONSTRAINT U_DogNumber UNIQUE(DogNumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

ALTER TABLE TblDog ADD CONSTRAINT U_DogTag UNIQUE(DogTag)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear as though Entity Framework supports it (yet), [but *was* on the cards](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/03/09/unique-constraints-in-the-entity-framework.aspx). Looks like you are going to need to do this directly in the database using [Unique Constraints as mentioned in the comments](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/02/05/sql-server-primary-key-constraints-and-unique-key-constraints/).

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxUniqueDog
ON TblDog (DogTag, DogNUmber)`

Comment: You really need two separate indexes, not one. If you just have one index you can still have hundreds of records with the same DogTag or the same DogNumber

Comment: well, it depends on the desired uniqueness. The OP is not specific on whether or not (D, 1) and (D, 2) should be allowed. This single index is, I believe, the quickest mechanism for his task of checking to see whether a dog exists before editing/inserting.