# How to allow in the field with a unique constraint to enter a lot of null values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
create table test3
(
id int PRIMARY KEY,
id2 int
);

create unique index ndx_id2 on test3 (id2);
```

For the purposes of unique indices, all `NULL` values are considered to different from all other `NULL` values and are thus unique. This is one of the two possible interpretations of the SQL-92 standard (the language in the standard is ambiguous) and is the interpretation followed by PostgreSQL, MySQL, Firebird, and Oracle.

Informix and Microsoft SQL Server follow the other interpretation of the standard.

```
INSERT INTO test3(id, id2) VALUES (1, null);
INSERT INTO test3(id, id2) VALUES (2, null);
```

Second INSERT returns

> A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index. [ Table name
>   = test3,Constraint name = ndx_id2 ]

Error in SQL Server but successfully adds record to another DBMS, Sqlite for example.

How to allow in the field with a unique constraint to enter a lot of null values ​​in SQL Server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From SQL Server 2008 and onwards, you can use a [filtered index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/767702/50552):

```
create unique index UX_YourIndex
on YourTable(col1) 
where col1 is not null
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dbf85/1/0)

For SQL Server 2005 and older ([9.0 corresponds to 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server)), you can use a surrogate column.  A surrogate column is a computed column.  It is computed as follows:

- When the semi-unique column is not `null`, the surrogate column is equal to that column
- When the semi-unique column is `null`, the surrogate column is equal to a unique id.  A unique id can be an identity column, a rowguid, or anything that is different for each row.

In other words, the surrogate column uses a unique string whenever the original column is `null`.  For example:

```
create table YourTable 
    (
    id int identity primary key
,   col1 int
,   surrogate1 as (coalesce(convert(varchar(20), col1), '_' + convert(varchar(20), id)))
    );

create unique index UX_YourIndex on YourTable(surrogate1);
```

It's your job to make sure that the surrogate values do not collide with real values.  In this example, I'm assuming that `col1` cannot start with an underscore.

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44521/1/0)

Comment: Your script does not allow null value. Conversely I need to add a lot of null values. Example: 1, 2, null, null, null, null, 3.

Comment: You should be allowed to insert multiple null values-- see example at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dbf85/1/0)

Comment: I guess my meal chose to be finished at the exact same time :)

Comment: Which sql server version is needed?
My local server version is 9.0.5000 throw: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: 9.0 is SQL Server 2005.  I've added a solution for older versions of SQL Server.

Comment: Filtered indexes where added in v10 (SQL Server 2008)