# How to allow in the field with a unique constraint to enter a lot of null values in SQL CE

Tags: sql-server-ce

```
create table test3
(
id int PRIMARY KEY,
id2 int
);

create unique index ndx_id2 on test3 (id2);
```

For the purposes of unique indices, all `NULL` values are considered to different from all other `NULL` values and are thus unique. This is one of the two possible interpretations of the SQL-92 standard (the language in the standard is ambiguous) and is the interpretation followed by PostgreSQL, MySQL, Firebird, and Oracle.

Informix and Microsoft SQL Server follow the other interpretation of the standard.

```
INSERT INTO test3(id, id2) VALUES (1, null);
INSERT INTO test3(id, id2) VALUES (2, null);
```

Second INSERT returns

> A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index. [ Table name
>   = test3,Constraint name = ndx_id2 ]

Error in SQL CE but successfully adds record to another DBMS, Sqlite for example.

How to allow in the field with a unique constraint to enter a lot of null values ​​in SQL CE?

P.S. This problem resolved for Sql 2008 [How to allow in the field with a unique constraint to enter a lot of null values ​​in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852103/how-to-allow-in-the-field-with-a-unique-constraint-to-enter-a-lot-of-null-values) but need decision for SQL CE

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server Compact, only unique values are allowed, including a singel NULL value.

Comment: I hope you understand that this is wrong. Maybe there are some opportunities to get around this problem?

Comment: Yes and need find decision for this problem