# JPA - Assign different unique constrains for two subclass of a SINGLE_TABLE hierarchy abstract class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 3 classes that are:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Tag {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints=
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"name"}))
public class SystemTag extends Tag {

}

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints=
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name", "user"}))
public class CustomTag extends Tag{
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
}
```

so I want to use unique name for system tags, and unique name-user pair for custom tags (multiple users can create same tags) But I get two warnings as below:

```
<timestamp> WARN  AnnotationBinder:601 - HHH000139: Illegal use of @Table in a subclass of a SINGLE_TABLE hierarchy: <domain>.CustomTag
<timestamp> WARN  AnnotationBinder:601 - HHH000139: Illegal use of @Table in a subclass of a SINGLE_TABLE hierarchy: <domain>.SystemTag
```

And it allows me to create two system tags with same name and two custom tags with same name for same user.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using a single table that is obviously not going to work.

Switch to using JOINED strategy

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Tag {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

and you will then have a table for CustomTag and table for SystemTag with unique constraints as expected.

Comment: in project design team leader decided to use it as single table but i guess i should use it as joined or table per class. thanks anyway :)

Comment: well you may be able to use 1 table with discriminator. Depends on your unique key requirements. If you create the key on name/user and forget about the name unique that might work depending on your db. e.g for records 1/alan/null, 2/alan/abc, 3/alan/xyz should be no issues: http://stackoverflow.com/a/767702/1356423