# EF 6.1 Unique Nullable Index

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

In EF 6.1 using Code First you can create Indexes using Attributes in your Entities or using the fluent API along the lines of:

```
 Property(x => x.PropertyName)
                .IsOptional()
                .HasMaxLength(450)
                .HasColumnAnnotation("Index",
                    new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_IndexName") {IsUnique = true,  }));
```

Is there any way to say scaffold `WHERE PropertyName IS NOT NULL` in the same way you would in SQL Server natively (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/767702/52026)?

Answer (score 64):

I didn't find a way to tell EF to use this where clause but here is some workaround. Check if it fit in your case.

1. Install Entity Framework, Define your DbContext, entities, conn string in app.config etc.
2. Enable Migration - run in Package Manager Console '-EnableMigration'
3. Create DbMigration - run in Package Manager Console 'Add-Migration MigrationName'
4. In the created DbMigration class in ovverided `Up` method run your sql for creating of unique nullable index.

code:

```
// Add unique nullable index 
string indexName = "IX_UQ_UniqueColumn";
string tableName = "dbo.ExampleClasses";
string columnName = "UniqueColumn";

Sql(string.Format(@"
    CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX {0}
    ON {1}({2}) 
    WHERE {2} IS NOT NULL;",
    indexName, tableName, columnName));
```

Note: don't forget to create a downgrade, too. Ovveride `Down` method and use `DropIndex` method inside:

```
DropIndex(tableName, indexName);
```

Also you may need some additional code if there is already data in your database which can conflict with the unique index constraint.

<strike>NOTE: Here you can use the CreateIndex method but I couldn't manage to create the correct index with it. EF just ignore my anonymousArguments or I write them wrong. You can try it yourself and write here with your result. The syntax is as follow:</strike>

```
CreateIndex(
    table: "dbo.ExampleClasses",
    columns: new string[] { "UniqueColumn" },
    unique: true,
    name: "IX_UniqueColumn",
    clustered: false,
    anonymousArguments: new
    {
        Include = new string[] { "UniqueColumn" },
        Where = "UniqueColumn IS NOT NULL"
    });
```

5 Try to add two etries with null values for the unique column and other equal values.

Here is my demo code - [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/HANYeum0)

Comment: Thanks Viktor! It works perfectly for me. On the other hand "anonymousArguments" are provider dependant, and SQL Server just ignore it.

Comment: The Create index solution doesn't work I prefer you remove it because it confused me in the beginning. Thanks Viktor

Comment: Really too bad that the anonymousArguments approach didn't work. There seems to be a lack of documentation around it as well. What values  are supported etc.

Comment: If your table name happens to be a reserved word, you'll have to escape it, e.g. `tableName = "dbo.\"User\"";` (at least for SQL Server)

Comment: Also, in my case I had to remove an existing unique index, which was named `IX_{UniqueColumn}`. (So no `UQ_` prefix.)

Comment: Nice! Don't forget to create a downgrade too, ok.

Comment: I get the error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.                CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UK_InsUser_Alt
               ON dbo.InstitutionUser(AlternateId)
               WHERE AlternateId IS NOT NULL;

Comment: I'm on EF core and receiving `The name 'Sql' does not exist in the current context` when trying this.

Answer (score 25):

In EF Core you can use the HasFilter method in the fluent API to achieve what you're looking for without adding custom SQL to the migration.

```
builder.Entity<Table>()
    .HasIndex(x => x.PropertyName)
    .HasName("IX_IndexName")
    .HasFilter("PropertyName IS NOT NULL");
```

This generates a migration like this:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_IndexName",
    table: "Table",
    columns: new[] { "PropertyName" },
    filter: "PropertyName IS NOT NULL");
```

Comment: .IsUnique() seems to be missing from the statement above

Answer (score 4):

**No**, you cannot *natively* do it.

But I created a custom SQL generator that enables the following:

1. Sort the columns in your index `ASC` or `DESC`
2. Enable the use of the `WHERE` keyword

To be able to use it, you must tweak your index name only. The name is separated in 3 parts by `:`. The parts are:

1. Index name
2. Sort orders
3. Where clause

If you have an index on 2 columns, need `Column1` to be sorted `ASC` and `Column2` `DESC`, and need a `where` clause, your index name would be:

```
var uniqueName = "UN_MyIndex:ASC,DESC:Column1 IS NOT NULL";
```

And you simply use it like this:

```
Property(t => t.Column1)
            .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute(uniqueName) { IsUnique = true, Order = 1 }));

Property(t => t.Column2)
            .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute(uniqueName) { IsUnique = true, Order = 2 }));
```

Then, in your `Configuration.cs` file, add this line in your constructor:

```
SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new CustomSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator());
```

Finally, create the `CustomSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator.cs` file as shown: [code here](https://gist.github.com/maximejobin/7f576c1973da1c573762c2feeeb75401).

Answer (score 1):

Basing on Viktor's answer I come up with solution creating this code automatically.

Final migration file should not use `CreateIndex` method but the one I named `CreateIndexNullable`. This method I created in `DbMigrationEx` which extends `DbMigration`

```
protected void CreateIndexNullable(string table, string column, string name)
{
    Sql($@"CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [{name}] ON {table}([{column}] ASC) WHERE([{column}] IS NOT NULL);");
}
```

How to change migration class code?

In `Configuration` class which is created in Migration folder I set

```
CodeGenerator = new CSharpMigrationCodeGeneratorIndexNullable();
```

My `CSharpMigrationCodeGeneratorIndexNullable` class extends `CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator`.
I'm not gonna show exact class content, I'll just present the idea.
Basing on `CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator` content I overrode some methods. The Entity Framework project is available at https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6.

To change migration class to `DbMigrationEx` I used method

```
Generate(IEnumerable<MigrationOperation> operations, string @namespace, string className)
```

The only thing that needs change is

```
WriteClassStart(
    @namespace, className, writer, "DbMigration", designer: false,
    namespaces: GetNamespaces(operations));
```

To change migration method to `CreateIndexNullable` I used method

```
Generate(CreateIndexOperation createIndexOperation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
```

You need to change line

```
writer.Write("CreateIndex(");
```

Also

```
WriteIndexParameters(createIndexOperation, writer);
```

to

```
writer.Write(", ");
writer.Write(Quote(createIndexOperation.Name));
```

But how to know if index must be nullable?

`createIndexOperation` paramter contains index information. I was not able to modify `CreateIndexOperation` creating, but its `Table`, `Name` and `Columns` properties could be enough to get to fields in entity class and get `Index` attribute which can be extended.

Answer (score -1):

With EF 6 you can do nonclustered unique index like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<T>()
                .HasIndex(index => index.Column, "idx_column_notnull")
                .IsUnique()
                .HasFilter("column IS NOT NULL")
                .IsClustered(false);
```

Comment: This question is about EF6 classic (not core). Moreover, you're repeating [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53088511/861716).

Comment: EF6 has no method ".HasFilter"