# How to create conditional unique constraint using EF code first approach?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, data-annotations

I need to add unique constraint on column allowing null which can be achieved using the following query:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_yourcolumn_notnull
ON YourTable(yourcolumn)
WHERE yourcolumn IS NOT NULL;
```

How can I achieve it using Entity Framework code first approach ?

Comment: There is `Index` attribute which could be applied to the property of the entity... But unfortunately, there is no `Condition` property for this attribute

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361518/ef-6-1-unique-nullable-index

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF 6.1 Unique Nullable Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361518/ef-6-1-unique-nullable-index)

Comment: @HemidAbbasov yea you are right I was required to add it using migration instead of using index attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a migration to add the index:

```
public partial class CreateDatabase : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql("CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ourcolumn_notnull
ON YourTable(yourcolumn)
WHERE yourcolumn IS NOT NULL;");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I think also inside down() method I should add "drop index index_name" if I want to revert my migration

Comment: @SimpleCode yes you should add the drop index in the Down method