# I want to set a Unique Constraint that allows nulls using SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql-server, unique-constraint, sql-server-2014-express

I want to set a unique constraint that allows nulls using SQL Server 2014 Express. I know this has been asked before but it was asked 5 years ago in this post.

[How do I create a unique constraint that also allows nulls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767657/how-do-i-create-a-unique-constraint-that-also-allows-nulls)

I am only starting to study SQL so I want to see if any other options have become available since 5 years ago.

I am consdiering using a Unique Filtered Index but i would like to avoid having to use this Index if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Unique constraints are indexes too. (Implicit.)

Comment: I just wanted confirmation that the previous answer is the correct one as it has been a long time since it was asked. Ive accepted Baris's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer(s) to the question you linked still apply and are correct and there seems to be no other way so far.

There is a [ticket on Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299229/change-unique-constraint-to-allow-multiple-null-values) for this since 2007. As suggested there and [here](http://improvingsoftware.com/2010/03/26/creating-a-unique-constraint-that-ignores-nulls-in-sql-server/) your best options are to use a filtered index or a computed column, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE [Orders] (
  [OrderId] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [TrackingId] varchar(11) NULL,
  ...
  [TrackingIdUnique] AS (
      CASE WHEN [TrackingId] IS NULL
      THEN '#' + cast([OrderId] as varchar(12))
      ELSE [TrackingId_Unique] END
  ),
  CONSTRAINT [UQ_TrackingIdUnique] UNIQUE ([TrackingIdUnique])
)
```

Comment: Thank you Baris for confirming that the previous answer is still the correct one.