# UNIQUE Column with multiple NULL values in visual studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-ce

I want to have a UNIQUE constraint on my `Barcode` column which may contain null values.

How do I create the constraint that allows multiple null values?

I use a local `Database.sdf` file (Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 with the .NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0).

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/767702/1560398) :

```
SqlCeConnection con = null;
con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.sdf");
con.Open();

try
{
    SqlCeCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Barcodex ON Products(Barcode) WHERE Barcode IS NOT NULL";
    cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

but it is not working.

The error I got :

> There was an error parsing the query,[Token line number =1,Token line offset =64,Token in error = WHERE]

Any help?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: Filtered Indexes are **NOT supported** in **SQL Server Compact 4.0**

Ref: [Differences Between SQL Server Compact and SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140(v=sql.110).aspx)

The TSQL syntax is correct. **(Assuming you have SQL Server 2008+. Filtered Indexes were introduced in SQL Server 2008)**

Change this:

```
        cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

to this

```
        cmd.ExecutNonQuery();
```

Also, you should wrap your connection in a `using` block.

Comment: I have a unique column on each row , I tried @GordonLinoff code below but it throw error `There was an error parsing the query,[Token line number =1,Token line offset =64,Token in error = AS]`

Answer (score 0):

Filtered indexes were introduced in SQL Server 2008.  Prior to that version, you would get an error on the `where` clause in such a statement.  If you are using a more recent version, perhaps your compatibility settings are causing the problem.

The compatibility level is a way to have a given version of SQL Server behave like an earlier version.  Levels 80 and 90 are for 2000 and 2005, so would not allow your syntax.  [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx) is some documentation.

If you have a unique id on each row, then you can use a computed column and unique index for the same effect:

```
alter table product add barcode_productid as (case when barcode is null then productid end);

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Barcodex ON Products(Barcode, barcode_productid);
```

Comment: Could you explain what compatibility settings could cause this problem ?

Comment: The code throw an error `There was an error parsing the query,[Token line number =1,Token line offset =64,Token in error = WHERE]`