# Fluent NHibernate: unique column that allows multiple NULL values

Tags: sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, unique, unique-constraint

I've got a column in a table that needs to be unique when a value is present, but should allow multiple NULL values. In SQL, I can do this using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767657/how-do-i-create-a-unique-constraint-that-also-allows-nulls) answer, but is there a way to configure this using Fluent NHibernate?

```
            Map(x => x.UniqueProperty).Unique().Nullable();
```

...does not work, and creates an unfiltered unique constraint that does not allow multiple NULL values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that in NHibernate, that is, NHibernate won't let you create this kind of constraint. Yes, it is possible, for example, in SQL Server, if you create a unique index which does not apply to NULLS:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_UniqueProperty_notnull
ON dbo.T1(UniqueProperty)
WHERE UniquePropertyIS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thats a shame...is there a good reason for this, or is it just a missing feature?

Comment: Well, I guess it's a missing feature... you can use auxiliary database objects in NHibernate (http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/index.html), but I don't think there is a Fluent NHibernate method for it. I could be wrong, though!

Comment: You can create the index in an hbm mapping by using the <database-object> XML tag.  So something like this:

<database-object>
    <create>
        CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Unique_Property
        ON Table(Property)
        WHERE Property IS NOT NULL
    </create>
    <drop>
        DROP INDEX IX_Unique_Property ON Table
     </drop>
</database-object>

Seems to work fine and produces the desired results.