# Entity framework Core set unique one to one relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have 2 models which must be one to one relation

```
public class Reference
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Matrix
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int ReferenceId {get;set;}
    public Reference Reference {get;set; }
}
```

One Matrix can only have one Reference and One Reference can only have one Matrix

Here is the problem, the Reference can exist without a Matrix, ReferenceId must be unique on the Matrix

How can i do this besides making the foreign key nullable but still unique?

Comment: Make it nullable and add a UniqueIndex? Look here if you are using SQL Server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767657/how-do-i-create-a-unique-constraint-that-also-allows-nulls/767702#767702

Comment: Yes but i am using Entity Framework Core

Comment: So...? How does that matter? You can configure that through EF Core as long as your database allows that

Comment: *"Reference can exist without a Matrix"* This doesn't require changing the model. Nullable FK will be needed if "Matrix can exist without a Reference".

Comment: Ah i understand thanks. I i think i just need an unique index on Matrix since it cannot exist without a Reference

Comment: Just configure [one-to-one relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#one-to-one). EF Core will add unique index automatically for you (in case you are using migrations).