# With SQL Server I want a unique index on only the non-null values

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server UNIQUE constraint with duplicate NULLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796414/sql-server-unique-constraint-with-duplicate-nulls)

In Sql Server I would like to have a column that has both nulls and real values. If the column has a value, I want to insure it is unique. The column could have multiple rows with null for this column.

For example suppose I had a table of books with 3 columns, namely:

```
Book Number - identity
Title - varchar
ISBN - char
```

Now the table would have a primary key with the identity column, which is good. The question would be on the ISBN column. I do not want any ISBN number to appear in the table more than once, but there will be many books with no ISBN number (since I don't know it).

Is there any way (or what is the best way) to inforce this constraint on ISBN?

Comment: No can do. Perhaps you can use a CHECK?

Comment: @astander: which is itself a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191421/how-to-create-a-unique-index-on-a-null-column which duplicates many others. let's just answer the question? :)

Comment: @Andomar, which then defeats the purpose of *close->Duplicate question*

Comment: @astander: Perhaps 0.001% of duplicates is actually closed as duplicate.  And some of those that get closed are not real duplicates.

Comment: I agree, this is answered previously in the referenced question, sorry.

Comment: @Andomar, lets hope that is a proven statistic? X-)

Comment: @astander: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680867/group-by-date-confirm-pending. No close votes, nice answer, overall the goodness of stackoverflow-- but definitely a duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008, you can create a filtered index, like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX indexName ON tableName(isbn) WHERE isbn IS NOT NULL
```

In earlier versions, create a calculated column which is the ISBN when it exists, and the primary key when the ISBN is null:

```
CREATE TABLE tableName (
    pk int identity(1,1) primary key,
    isbn int NULL,
    nullbuster as (case when isbn is null then pk else 0 end),
    CONSTRAINT dupNulls_uqX UNIQUE (isbn)
)
```

Copied from [SQL Server UNIQUE constraint with duplicate NULLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796414/sql-server-unique-constraint-with-duplicate-nulls), so this is in wiki mode :)