# group by date, confirm, pending

Tags: mysql, sql

im trying to build chart for users for each day with total confirmed user and total pending users for that each day and i need data like following:

```
date         |   confirmed    |  pending
2010-01-05   |   5            |  2      
2010-01-06   |   10           |  3
```

following is the structure of the table:

```
user_id
username
confirm     enum(0,1)
date        date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Date, SUM(CASE Confirm WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Confirmed,
  SUM(CASE Confirm WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Pending,
 FROM Table
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: its working fine for confirmed, but not counting the pending at all.. i even limited the rows to show pending only with (where confirm = '0') it shows rows, but does not sum the pending at all

Comment: There's a typo in the code. There shouldn't be a comma after "Pending". I corrected that typo here, quoted the column name "Date", which is a reserved word, and got the expected results using PostgreSQL.