# Unique constraint on another column if not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create this table with the following constrains, is it possible to do with SQL Server Management Studio?

- Id
- ProductId [Nullable column]
- CompanyId [Nullable column]
- Username [unique for every productId - IF DeletedAt is not NULL]
- Identifier [Nullable column] [unique for every companyId - IF DeletedAt is not NULL]
- DeletedAt [Nullable column]

Update:
My table create query is the following:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    [ProductId] [int] NULL,
    [CompanyId] [int] NULL,
    [Username] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Identifier] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [DeletedAt] [datetime2](7) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: I guess you would you [INSTEAD OF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql) trigger to force business rules constraints.

Comment: so you can have 2 JohnSmith usernames for productID 1 as long as both have a DeletedAt value?

Comment: @dfundako Yes exactly.

Comment: You can create these constraints but with such a complex logic in constraints, you will get a performance hit, I would suggest to use Stored Procedures (for updates, inserts and deletes) to handle the business logic and do not use such convoluted  constraints.

Comment: Is "DeletedAt" a DateTime, by any chance?  When I read the requirements my first thought was "that's a slowly changing dimension and he's using 'DeletedAt' as a logical deletion flag."  If I'm right, you can just add DeletedAt to the unique constraint.  Alternately, you could make an archival table and whenever you delete a record from your main table you make a copy of it in your archive table.

Comment: @JohnyL Could you be more specific and give me an example of this trigger just to help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [conditional unique constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866061/conditional-unique-constraint)

Comment: I gave you a link in my comment. It's all described there.

Comment: @Brian yes its a datetime2 datatype. Would it really work? Because DeletedAt is not unique, only if null.. I cant seem to work it out in my head if it will work.

Comment: I assumed that "DeletedAt" is being set programmatically, so it will be unique as a practical matter unless you manage to delete multiple records at precisely the same moment (down to the millisecond).  That said, a filtered index might be a better way to go.

Comment: @Brian Okay thanks for your help. i'm looking into the filtered indexes as being proposed as answers.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a `unique filtered index`.  Here you go for the table:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[the_table]    Script Date: 7/26/2018 4:04:00 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[the_table](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [productid] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [companyid] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [username] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [identifier] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [deletedat] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_the_table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And the index for username:

```
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

/****** Object:  Index [UIDX_USERNAME]    Script Date: 7/26/2018 4:03:31 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UIDX_USERNAME] ON [dbo].[the_table]
(
    [username] ASC
)
WHERE ([DELETEDAT] IS NOT NULL)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

It would be the same index logic for the other column, but I don't want to clutter this answer by posting more!  I would not mess around with putting the logic in triggers or stored proc's, bad data could still sneak in.  If you keep nice constraints, nobody can clutter your data up :)

Comment: Hi. I get the following error when trying to do the index:
Column 'Username' in table 'dbo.User' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.

Comment: I just updated my question with the create table statement. Maybe I made some changes that did some unexpected

Comment: @CodingAcademy I don't think you can have a index on a `VARCHAR(MAX)` data type.  What you _could_ do is change it to `VARCHAR(8000)` or something more reasonable, like maybe 100.   I doubt you'd have a username that is really that big :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a unique index on ProductId and Username, and use a where clause to restrict that index to `WHERE DeletedAt IS NOT NULL`. [Answer showing an example of a unique filtered index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4677428/5198140).

You may also need the clause `AND ProductId IS NOT NULL`, although that wasn't stated as a requirement, but since that column is nullable you ought to think about this.

Similar for `Identifier`.

You might also want to think about the value of a table where it is valid to have a row where all the columns except `Id` are null...

Answer (score 1):

You can use filtered indexes.  The syntax looks like this:

```
create unique index unq_thetable_username on the_table(username)
    where deleteAt is not null;
```

I don't know if you can point-and-click your way to this solution.  I would just write the logic as above.

Comment: I get an error with your syntax: Column 'Username' in table 'dbo.User' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index. Is it because its not nullable?

Comment: @CodingAcademy . . . This works fine on SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1f357.