# Unique constraint only over NON-NULL columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In MS SQL Server 2008, is it possible to define `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on a column BUT which is checked IF and ONLY IF for NON-NULL values. That is, there will be many NULLs which should be ignored. For non-nulls it should be unique, however.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server UNIQUE constraint with duplicate NULLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796414/sql-server-unique-constraint-with-duplicate-nulls) (and plenty of others)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a *Filtered Index*:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX User_PinNr_IUC
ON [User] (pinNr)
WHERE pinNr IS NOT NULL
```

Refering to [CREATE INDEX (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx)

> **WHERE < filter_predicate > :**
>   Creates a filtered index by specifying
>   which rows to include in the index.
>   The filtered index must be a
>   nonclustered index on a table. Creates
>   filtered statistics for the data rows
>   in the filtered index.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any difference between CREATE INDEX and ADD CONSTRAINT? And please, how to write a condition for varchar NULL or EMPTY/WHITESPACE?

Comment: @James: CREATE INDEX is an independent statement. ADD CONSTRAINT used in CREATE/ALTER TABLE statements.

Comment: @James: VARCHARColumn is null OR VARCHARColumn = ""