# H2 database: unique constraint only over non-NULL values? (filtered index)

Tags: sql, h2

SQL Server 2008 [apparently has filtered indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394800/unique-constraint-only-over-non-null-columns).

What is the cleanest way to achieve the same in H2?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use a computed column for this purpose . . . assuming you have a unique id.  Let me assume the unique id is numeric and never negative.  Then:

```
alter table t add col (case when <condition> then -1 else uniqueid end);

create unique index unq_t_col on t(col);
```

I believe that H2 supports unique indexes, computed columns, and indexes on computed columns, so this should work.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I will test this approach. Still wondering if there is a solution that does not require an additional table column.