# Limit column value to 0 or to be unique on insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where a int column should either be set to zero or to a value which does not already exist in the table. Can I prevent inserting non zerod duplicated values in such column with a CHECK CONSTRAINT or should I use a BEFORE INSERT trigger? in case I could do this with both, what design is better?

From the .NET windows forms application we are using a global transaction scope to wrap the save and in both cases I would like the insert to fail and the transaction to roll back completely so I don't know if I should put the rollback inside the trigger, that's why I would rather try with a check if possible.

Database: SQL 2008

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server UNIQUE constraint with duplicate NULLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796414/sql-server-unique-constraint-with-duplicate-nulls)

Comment: @Andriy, the question you quoted is not 100% the same but it looks interesting, being in SQL 2008 a filtered unique index which excludes the zeros would probably be the best option, so no triggers and no checks :) I will try it out, Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the link in Andriy M's comment, it mention a 2008 new concept : filtered index...

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX indexName ON tableName(columns) INCLUDE includeColumns WHERE columnName != 0`

This will create an index of unique items that are not 0.

Any attempt to insert a duplicate non-zero value will breach the uniqueness of the index and cause an error.

Answer (score 2):

why are you using zero instead of null.?  If you had it as null then the db would handle it for you easily via a nullable unique constraint..

Comment: Legacy design I cannot change.

Answer (score 1):

Check constraint, when used properly, prevent bad data. They do not change the bad data to good. For that reason, I would aim for a trigger instead. If you can get around the need for a 0 as NULL, you could use a unique constraint, but supplying the answer would be the job of a trigger regardless.

Comment: I can't get rid of the 0 :( I don't know if I can even transform the bad data into a good one, if a non zero duplicated value is provided, it has to fail not to set it as zero.

Comment: If you can't get rid of the zero, I would try the trigger first, as the constraint is more likely to be problematic due to the heavy checking of the table.

Comment: Thanks Gregory but I go for the filtered index, just trying to avoid trigger as much as I can, I don't really like to much of pre/post insert or update logic... just a philosophical thing :)