# How can I create a Unique Constraint that allows NULL values with Hibernate annotations?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am using: Spring 4, Hibernate 4, SQL Server 2008

I know how to do it with SQL Server 2008 from this question response [How do I create a unique constraint that also allows nulls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767657/how-do-i-create-a-unique-constraint-that-also-allows-nulls)

But since I don't generate any manual SQL code during the creation of the table, is it possible to generate a "where clause" in my constraint through Hibernate annotations in my Entity class?

My DDL is created from scratch with the java entity definition as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Neighborhood", 
uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"codecnbv","zipcode"})})
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
public class Neighborhood implements Serializable {

private String id;
private String codecnbv;
private String zipcode;

@Id 
@Column(name="id", nullable=false, unique=true, length=2)
public String getId() {
    return this.id;
}

@Column(name="codecnbv", nullable=true, length=12) //explicitly nullable
public String getCodecnbv() {
    return codecnbv;
}

@Column(name="zipcode", nullable=true, length=5) //explicitly nullable
public String getZipcode() {
    return zipcode;
}
```

}

However, as soon as I add data and try to enter a second record with NULL in column codecnbv and/or zipcode, I receive an exception that says I've violated the unique constraint.

The requirement I have says that I must allow multiple null values, and when the value is not null, then I should have unique values i.e.

For zipcode column

1. 56000  --ok
2. NULL   --ok
3. 34089  --ok
4. NULL   --ok
5. 34089  --Not allowed
6. 34567  --ok

Comment: Please check what kind of constraints are really put on entities table. Run `show create table your_table_name`

Comment: A unique Constraint will Allow you ONE null value. If it allows you multiple null values then it wouldnt be Unique would it :)

Comment: @M.Ali I thought that NULL will not violate unique constraints. Lets have A that relates to B via FK and the relation is ONE - ONE but not mandatory. Your assumption would prevent creating such constraints

Comment: @M.Ali the old argument. `null` means no value, so there is no sense in applying the restriction of `unique` to it. In general I like SQL Server, but this is a major mistake.

Comment: @SJuan76 you are very wrong there my friend, in SQL Server NULL is not considered as no value but it is considered as `an Unknown value`. It can be no value or it can be any value.

Comment: @M.Ali if it is considere an unknown value then it should even more so not be considered a unique value. MySQL handles this more correct: "A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a key value that matches an existing row. For all engines, a UNIQUE index allows multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL."

Answer (score 1):

It is not an issue of Hibernate but of SQL Server, which considers `NULL` a value and does not allow a second `NULL` value. Wicked, I know.

Some links:

[How do I create a unique constraint that also allows nulls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767657/how-do-i-create-a-unique-constraint-that-also-allows-nulls)

http://sqlmag.com/database-development/multiple-nulls-unique-constraints

Comment: Another link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796414/sql-server-unique-constraint-with-duplicate-nulls

Comment: SJuan76 I see the point about NULL values in SQL Sever. I guess I will have to manage this business logic programatically. Thanks.