# Rails uniqueness constraint and matching db unique index for null column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, unique-index, validates-uniqueness-of

I have the following in my migration file

```
  def self.up
    create_table :payment_agreements do |t|
      t.boolean    :automatic, :default => true, :null => false
      t.string     :payment_trigger_on_order
      t.references :supplier
      t.references :seller
      t.references :product
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

I want to ensure that if a product_id is specified it is unique but I also want to allow null so I have the following in my model:

```
  validates :product_id,
            :uniqueness => true,
            :allow_nil => true
```

Works great but I should then add an index to the migration file

```
add_index :payment_agreements, :product_id, :unique => true
```

Obviously this will throw an exception when two null values are inserted for product_id. I could just simply omit the index in the migration but then there's the chance that I'll get two PaymentAgreements with the same product_id as shown here: [Concurrency and integrity](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M001400)

My question is what is the best/most common way to deal with this problem

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191421/how-to-create-a-unique-index-on-a-null-column

Comment: validates_uniqueness_of:product_id, :if => lambda { !self.product_id.nil? }

Answer (score 11):

it depends on your db server.
as for mysql:

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint
>   such that all values in the index must
>   be distinct. An error occurs if you
>   try to add a new row with a key value
>   that matches an existing row. This
>   constraint does not apply to NULL 
>   values except for the BDB storage
>   engine. For other engines, **a UNIQUE
>   index allows multiple NULL values for
>   columns that can contain NULL.**

Answer (score 0):

Some major database systems do not allow a unique index to contain multiple NULLs: unique applies to NULLs as well as non-NULLs. There are ways around this on the database level (e.g., triggers, or a computed column; see [link text](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/17/60209.aspx)).

You could address this on an application level and put in a validation that checks for uniqueness if the `product_id` is not null.

```
validate :enforce_unique_product_id
def enforce_unique_product_id
  if (!self.product_id.nil? &&
      PaymentAgreement.exists?(:conditions=>['product_id = ?', self.product_id]))
    errors.add_to_base('There is already an agreement with product id " + 
                       self.product_id)
  end
end
```

(Update: As pointed out by zed_0xff, MySql allows multiple NULLs in a UNIQUE index in the most commonly used storage engines.)