# Nullable One To One Relationships with Integer Keys in LINQ-to-SQL

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, one-to-one

I have two objects (`Foo` and `Bar`) that have a one-to-zero-or-one relationship between them. So, Foo has a nullable foreign key reference to Bar.ID and a ([nullbusted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191421/how-to-create-a-unique-index-on-a-null-column)) unique index to enforce the "1" side. Bar.ID is an int, and so Foo.BarID is a nullable int.

The problem occurs in the LINQ-to-SQL DBML mapping of .NET types to SQL datatypes. Since `int` is not a nullable type in .NET, it gets wrapped in a `Nullable<int>`. However, this is not the same type as `int`, and so Visual Studio gives me this error message when I try to create the OneToOne Association between them:

> Cannot create an association "Bar_Foo". Properties do not have matching types: "ID", "BarID".

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Stuck with the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I've worked around this by setting Bar.ID (the primary key) to `CanBeNull="true"`, which is definitely ugly. I'm hoping for a better solution here.

Comment: I definitely do not want to do this as we refresh our dbml file regularly and it would get overwritten. Did you ever find a better way?

Comment: Nope, never did, though I stopped looking long ago. Perhaps your dbml-refreshing tool can be set to reimplement this change?