# TSQL - Distinct Question

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, distinct

I have the following unique contstraint defiend on a table:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Access_AccessSOE] ON [dbo].[Access] 
(
    [AccessSOE] ASC
)
```

I am trying to import records to this table using the following query:

```
INSERT INTO Access 
  (AccessSOE, AccessName, AccessBox, AccessLocation, 
   AccessBusiness, AccessPhone, AccessFax, AccessEmail,
   LastUpdatedBy, Deleted, AccessPrimaryKey)
SELECT DISTINCT(i.AccessSOE), i.AccessName, i.AccessBox, i.AccessLocation,
       i.AccessBusiness, i.AccessPhone, i.AccessFax, i.AccessEmail,
       'Admin', 0, i.IndexNew
  FROM Access_IMPORT i
 WHERE i.AccessSOE NOT IN (SELECT a.AccessSOE FROM ACCESS a)
```

However the import fails. The only unique constraint on the table is the AccessSOE field, and I thought by selecting only distinct items, my query would be correct.

Can anyone provide any help?

Comment: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Access' with unique index 'IX_Access_AccessSOE'.

Comment: Are you inserting into a clean table? E.g. no chance for duplicates? If there's a chance for duplicates then you NOT IN (SELECT...) query might have to UNION with data from the target table iteself to avoid the dupes.

Comment: @Paul - the `NOT IN` is selecting from the target table.

Comment: @JNK: i meant the target of the import, so the not in subselect would look something like: ...FROM ACCESS UNION ...FROM Access_IMPORT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First**, try changing

```
Where i.AccessSOE not in (Select a.AccessSOE from Access a)
```

Into:

```
Where NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM Access a WHERE a.AccessSOE = i.AccessSOE)
```

Any NULLs here will `Select a.AccessSOE from Access a` cause the *entire* NOT IN to be false

**Then**, check you haven't duplicates in what you insert. DISTINCT applies to all columns BTW

```
SELECT COUNT(*), i.AccessSOE, i.AccessName, i.AccessBox, i.AccessLocation,
       i.AccessBusiness, i.AccessPhone, i.AccessFax, i.AccessEmail,
       'Admin', 0, i.IndexNew
  FROM Access_IMPORT i
 where NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT * FROM Access a WHERE a.AccessSOE = i.AccessSOE)
GROUP BY
      i.AccessSOE, i.AccessName, i.AccessBox, i.AccessLocation,
       i.AccessBusiness, i.AccessPhone, i.AccessFax, i.AccessEmail,
       'Admin', 0, i.IndexNew
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: +1 for `EXISTS` but, can he have a `NULL` on a column with a unique index?

Comment: @JNK With the obvious exception of primary keys, aren't `unique` and `nullable` separate constraints?

Comment: @djacobson - yeah but I wasn't sure it would be allowed as a value regardless(since by definition `NULL` is a non-value...like  you can't `NULL` a pk).  In my experience I haven't had to use unique indexes.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191421/how-to-create-a-unique-index-on-a-null-column) has some interesting information about the concept. Sounds like it's at least somewhat implementation-dependent...

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that the confusing `DISTINCT(i.AccessSOE)` syntax is legal, the DISTINCT applies across all the columns you're selecting, not just on `i.AccessSOE`, so you could have duplicates of those as long as the combination of all the selected columns is unique.

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT DISTINCT` returns rows where all columns combine to create a distinct row.  Your unique constraint enforces the rule that `AccessSOE` must be unique.  Can you check your data to see if there are duplicate values fro `AccessSOE`, where other columns make the row distinct?