# How to perform logic delete with unique field in db

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table with those fields

```
Field 1 > ActivityID (PK, NOT NULL)
Field 2 > Alias (Unique) (NULL)
Field 3 > IsActive (NULL)
```

I want to do a logic delete by that I mean that I don't want to delete the row.
I want to change the field IsActive to 0 and the field Alias to NULL

But my problem is that I can't change the Alias Field to NULL because he is unique.

How can do a logic delete with Unique field, when I need to delete the value in the Unique field also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL 2008 & up, use a filtered index to not include NULL in the index.

SQL 2005 and earlier, Alias alone cannot have a unique constraint, be NULLable and be of much use. So, you can use the computed column technique to get around that. See this answer for more...

[How to create a unique index on a NULL column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191421/how-to-create-a-unique-index-on-a-null-column)

Comment: tanks...
i hope that there is a way to do this with unique field

Answer (score 0):

In short: you can't. Having  a column declared as `unique` requires that each value in that column be unique. Having more than one `null` value violates that constraint.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly. Your Alias field is unique but allows nulls. That means there can only ever be one record with a null value.

If you need more than one record to have a null value in this field your database design needs to be changed such that your Alias field in not unique.