# Enforcing unique and multiple NULLS for a column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I enforce Unique values as well as multiple NULLS for a column of a table in SQL Server?

Comment: Meaning, only non-null values must be unique? Not identical, but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191421/how-to-create-a-unique-index-on-a-null-column

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you clarify?

Comment: @ Ash Burlaczenko I want a column to accept only unique values but we should be able to insert any number of null values.In sql server If you go for UIQUE constraint, then that allows only 1 NULL value.But I require multiple null values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767657/how-do-i-create-unique-constraint-that-also-allows-nulls-in-sql-server/767702#767702):

> In **SQL Server 2008**, you can define
>   a unique filtered index based on a
>   predicate that excludes NULLs:
>
> ```
> CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_yourcolumn_notnull
> ON YourTable(yourcolumn)
> WHERE yourcolumn IS NOT NULL;
> ```
>
> In earlier versions, you can resort to
>   VIEWS with a NOT NULL predicate to
>   enforce the constraint.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers mention filtered indexes and triggers.

Filtered indexes are SQL Server 2008 only. For earlier versions and to avoid code (trigger):

- Either you can use an indexed view with a IS NOT NULL filter. This is a DRI approach
- Or you can have a computed column with `ISNULL(TheColumn, -PKIdentityCol)` (or some other value based on the PK) which is also DRI

Comment: Forgive me for being dense, but what is DRI?

Comment: @Cheran S: [Declarative Referential Integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_Referential_Integrity): primary keys, foreign keys, unique/check/default/NULL/constraints etc