# The proper way to implement unique constraint that allows multiple NULL values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need 1 column in the table to hold unique non-null values or `NULL`. TSQL `UNIQUE` constraint treats 2 `NULL`s as equal, so I cannot make column unique.
What is the right way to handle this problem?
After doing some research, I found 2 methods which seem correct to me, but I cannot determine which one is better.
The first which is not applied to all cases:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
   null_or_unique_id INT, unique_key AS  
(CASE WHEN [null_or_unique_id] IS NULL THEN -(1)*[id] 
 ELSE [null_or_unique_id] END), UNIQUE(unique_key ));
```

It works but requires all allowed values of `null_or_unique_id` to be non-negative (that's ok in my case)
The second one :

```
 CREATE VIEW test_view WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 SELECT [null_or_unique_id] FROM dbo.test WHERE [null_or_unique_id] IS NOT NULL;
 GO
 CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX byNullOrUniqueId 
 ON dbo.test_view([null_or_unique_id]);
```

Surely, it's also possible to implement the desired functionality with triggers, but I think trigger solution will create more overhead then any of mentioned above.

What is the best practice for such a case?
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

4 ways:

- [Filtered index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) (SQL Server 2008) <- recommended based on your tags
- Trigger (mentioned)
- Indexed view (in your question)
- Unique constraint/index with computed column (in your question)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about filtered index - it's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

SQL 2008 allows you to define a filtered index - essentially an index with a `WHERE` clause - see Phil Haselden's asnwer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191421/how-to-create-a-unique-index-on-a-null-column) for MSDN links and an example.

Answer (score 2):

Normalise it. Move the column to a new table together with your current table's primary key. Make the column unique and not null in the new table. Nullable unique constraints make no logical sense and are of little or no practical use.