# Unique Constraint, excluding NULL values

Tags: sql-server-2005, constraints, unique-key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The proper way to implement unique constraint that allows multiple NULL values in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088361/the-proper-way-to-implement-unique-constraint-that-allows-multiple-null-values-in)

I have a column in my table where all the values must either be unique, or NULL.

I tried adding a Unique Key to the table for this column, but this seems to mean I can only have 1 NULL value?

How can I set a constraint so that all the values are unique, unless they are NULL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 has filtered indexes that allow this but they are not available in 2005. In SQL Server 2005 you can create an indexed view with definition

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Foo
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT bar
FROM dbo.baz
WHERE bar IS NOT NULL
```

Then create a unique clustered index on that.

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ix ON dbo.Foo(bar)
```