# SQL Server Unique Combination check constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique-constraint, check-constraints

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unique Constraint, excluding NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150540/unique-constraint-excluding-null-values)

Lets say i have a table with addresses, and i want an owner to have only One main address.
Fist do i define a index/key or a check constraint?
What's the expression for this?

```
TABLE_Address
--OwnerId
--IsMain    (not null able)
--City etc....
```

So i need a Unique combination of  ( `IsMain ==true AND ownerId`)

Comment: Please state version of SQL Server as answer varies. If 2008+ you can use a filtered index and if 2000/2005 an indexed view.

Comment: It's SQL Server 2012. Do filtered indexes require  that all other values except the unique one to be Null?

Comment: Ah sorry I thought I had chosen a duplicate that had example syntax for both. For filtered indexes you just need `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix ON TABLE_Address(ownerId) WHERE IsMain=1`

Comment: This statement also restricts the IsMain=false value into unique, so i can't have multiple non-main addresses...... Is this supposed to work with Null values only?

Comment: No it doesn't restrict IsMain=false to be unique as they aren't included in the filtered index at all. They are excluded by the `WHERE` clause. SQL Server doesn't have a boolean datatype and `false`. What datatype are you actually using? I assumed `bit` and therefore `1` or `0`

Comment: Yes my mistake forgot to delete the previous restriction ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a filtered unique index on `ownerId` with condition `IsMain = 1`. This index will a) enforce this condition and b) help your application to the pre-insert validation query.