# Database design : Could I make a column in a table only allows one 'true' for some specific rows and others false for same specific rows

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, database-design, entity-framework-4.1

**Problem statement** - [Business] 1---* [Branch] A business must have one or more branch(es). Only one branch can be main branch.

I am have two design in my mind

1. [**Branch table**] - {id, BusinessID (FK), Name, etc , **IsMainBranch**}
2. [**Branch table**] - {id, BusinessID (FK), Name, etc },  [**MainBranch table**] - {BranchID (PK, FK), BusinessID (FK)}.
3. [**Business table**] - {id, name, **mainbranchid**}, [**Branch table**] - {id, BusinessID (FK), Name, etc}

Problem with #1 - To put constrain on IsMainBranch I have to use triggers, which can go out of sync latter.

Problem with #2 - Bit complicated to access the data in EF.

Problem with #3 - Don't think its a good design.

I am using EF 4.1 as ORM and don't want to make things complicated, which design I should choose. Please suggest if there is a better/alternate way available for the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With SQL Server 2008+ you can use [filtered indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx)

In your `Branch` table, just have a flag `IsMainBranch`. Then create a unique filtered index: this will allow one row only where `IsMainBranch= 1` per Business.

Branch table:

```
id (PK)
BusinessID (FK)
Name
...
IsMainBranch
```

Then

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_MainBranch 
        ON Branch(BusinessID) 
        WHERE IsMainBranch = 1;
```

This gives

- simpler table structure
- no triggers
- the DB engine enforces this for you
- no circular FKs (no `MainBranchID` in the Business table)

Also see:

- [The proper way to implement unique constraint that allows multiple NULL values in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6088361/27535)
- [SQL Server bit column constraint, 1 row = 1, all others 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4810615/27535)

Answer (score 0):

Each "satellite" branch will have a main branch, correct?  So why not have a field "main branch".  If branch id == main branch, then it *is* a main branch.  Otherwise, it *refers* to the main branch.

You should *not* have an "isMainbranch" column.

"Branch type" column might be OK: types might include "main", "satellite", "ATM kiosk", etc.  But a boolean "isMainBranch"?  No.

IMHO...

Comment: A business must have only one main branch that's why I had IsMainBranch flag with each branch.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for number 3, create a mainBranchId in the business tables.

1) this will ensure that at any given time there is at most one main branch per business. (this might happen in the other 2 designs)

2) you won't need to create an extra table that is a replication of the branch table (this is what you would be doing in the 2nd design)