# Unique index on nullable column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with many records. Column X is nullable and a lot of records have NULL in this column. Can I create a UNIQUE non-clustered index on this column? Aren't those null values violating the unique constraint?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: here, [>>Click here for DEMO<<](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87e2b) *uncomment* the last line and build the schema again. see what happens.

Comment: [How to create a unique index on a NULL column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191421/how-to-create-a-unique-index-on-a-null-column?rq=1)

Comment: Check this for workaround - http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3711501/UNIQUE-Column-with-multiple-NULL-values.htm

Answer (score 9):

If you're on SQL Server **2008** or newer - you can set up a filtered, unique index to exclude / ignore all the `NULL` values.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX uixYourIndexName
ON dbo.YourTableName(YourColumnName)
WHERE YourColumnName IS NOT NULL
```

That would essentially "filter out" all `NULL` values - not including them into the index at all. Any query that uses the same `WHERE` clause can use this filtered index to find those rows.

Without the filtered index, you could **not** create a UNIQUE INDEX on your column since with a UNIQUE index, you're only allowed to have a single row that has `NULL` in that column.

Comment: Does this exclude rows with a null value, or exclude null values when creating the index?  IE with rows `1, 2, null` and `1, 2, null`, does this violate the constraint for third column `IS NOT NULL` or not?

Comment: @CaptainPrinny: the `WHERE` clause just skips any rows that match the condition - so here, any row with `NULL` in the `YourColumnName` will **not** be added to the index and cannot be found by using that index