# Unique constraint on a column excluding null values

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite3-ruby

I have a user database, it has Company column, it can be empty i.e null or may contain some value. But if contains any value, it should be unique. If I use the unique attribute in my model it is not allowing to have multiple null values for the column. I am using Sqlite3 db.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191421/how-to-create-a-unique-index-on-a-null-column

Comment: how can i do it in ruby on rails ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Model validation to handle it.  Perhaps something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :company

  validate do
    if self.company && User.where(company: self.company).first
      raise ArgumentError, "Company must be `nil` or unique"
    end
  end
end
```

It's a bit of a hack, but it should fit your needs.

Comment: `User.where(company: self.company).exists?` might be a better approach than `first`.

Comment: What if i make a function of this, and I want to run it everytime a new user is created. so how will do that ?

Comment: `validates` will run every time a `User` is created or updated, there is no need to create a separate method for it.

Comment: I think its running on every page and I am getting this error "You need to supply at least one attribute"

Comment: I figured it out i changed "validates" to "validate". Thanks a lot guyz for your help. I really appreciate it !

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry about that.  Updated for future reference.