# How to allow null value to be repeated?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have used this on my table

```
alter table Draftsmen
  ADD constraint uc_draftsmen UNIQUE([DraftsmanCNICNo])
```

It works but it also doesn't allow `NULL` values to be repeated since it's a unique constraint.

I want to allow `NULL` to be repeated. How to do in this constraint?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a unique index on a NULL column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191421/how-to-create-a-unique-index-on-a-null-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard SQL allows that but in SQL Server, you cannot do that.

Instead in **SQL Server 2008 and above**, you can create a unique filtered index and exclude `NULL`s

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Idx_columnName
ON tableName(columnName)
WHERE columnName IS NOT NULL
```